# How to create a zoom in and zoom out icon in flask app?

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a flask based UI where there are several html files inside templates and python main.py file. Below is a screenshot of my UI webpage:

[image]

As you can see there are two navigation tabs, Reports and Insight Engine.

In this page, I want to make a zoom in and zoom out button at right upper corner. Zoom out button will decrease the webpage size to 80% and zoom in button will increase the webpage size to 120%. They should work similar to ctrl+ and ctrl- in windows. These buttons should be available for both  the navigation tabs.

This is my directory structure:

```
/static
  /design.css
/templates
  /index.html
  /upload.html
  /engine.html
/main.py
```

How can I achieve this?

I am not attaching any code because I didn't try any solution as I didn't find any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [zoom CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom) :

```js
document.querySelector("#zoom").addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.body.style.zoom = 1.0;
});

document.querySelector("#zoomout").addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.body.style.zoom = 0.8;
});

document.querySelector("#zoomin").addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.body.style.zoom = 1.2;
});
```

```html
<button id="zoomout">Zoom -</button>
<button id="zoom">Restore zoom</button>
<button id="zoomin">Zoom +</button>
```

Note that it is [not supported on Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom#browser_compatibility).